# How do I find out how many bytes a character has?

Tags: php, byte, character

I was wondering how do I find out how many bytes does a character have?

Comment: What programming language? Or do you just want to look it up yourself on the internet? Also, which encoding? UTF-8?

Comment: PHP is the language I'm using UTF-8 encoding but what about the rest of them?

Comment: This is actually a tough question.  UTF-8, for instance, may have between 1 and 4 bytes.

Comment: how would I know if a certain letter or number or whatever has 1 byte or 4?

Comment: Mario just posted the right answer.  Better than the one I was crafting with ord().

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to find out how many UTF-8 bytes a letter in a PHP string has then:

```
print strlen(mb_substr($string, 0, 1, "utf-8"));
```

`strlen()` returns the raw byte length, while `mb_substr()` returns a "character" according to the charset/encoding. In this example from position `0`.

Comment: Note that for this to work you _might_ have to disable `mbstring.func_overload`, otherwise `strlen` is just `mb_strlen` with the internal character encoding. A `mb_strlen($string,'ASCII');` may be more portable.

Answer (score 6):

- ASCII is 7 bits.
- Most other languages use 8 bits (1 byte).
- Many eastern languages (Chinese, Japanese) use 16 bits (2 bytes).
- Unicode is usually 32 bits (4 bytes).

How a character is stored and represented depends on the programming language and the platform you are using.

Comment: is there a table that shows me how many bytes a letter has for instance?

Comment: @SyFY - There are tables, depending on the platform and programming language. I don't know what PHP uses internally.

Comment: unicode codepoints are 32bit, not 16. (UTF-16 can encode a single codepoint to two 16bit code units)

Comment: @Oded @Mat *Current* [Unicode standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) only specify a space of 20bits (just over a million codepoints) although I think that some *historic* versions may have allowed more codepoints (the original unicode was only 16bits). Many *values* which can be stored in a single UTF-32 "4 bytes" are *invalid* Unicode codepoints as the space is only defined for `0-0x10FFFF` (This may seem like a limitation, but it covers "foreseeable usage" and allows both UTF-8 and UTF-16 to have some rather nicer properties. Unicode does not try to be a binary transfer mechanism.)