# What is the Size of single character in php?

Tags: php

I want to know the memory capacity of the single character in php.

Please anyone give me the code or reference link to get the memory of a character.

Is there any predefined function for calculating the memory of a character as like

```
strlen();
```

I have the sample code for calculating the bandwidth of the webpage

This is the sample code

```
$speed = 10;

ob_start();

include(filename.php);
$now = time();
foreach(str_split(ob_get_clean(), $speed*1024) as $chunk)
{
    echo $chunk;
    flush();
    $now++;
    while($now > time())
    {
        usleep(1000000);
    }
}
```

From this i can get the number of character by using the ob_get_lenght().

If i know the memory of a character then i can find the bandwidth for the webpage

Comment: Not sure of what you mean. If you run `strlen()` on a multibyte character it'll tell you the byte count. E.g., ['€' uses 3 bytes in UTF-8](http://3v4l.org/dSpf5). Do you want to know the exact memory used by the Zend engine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086692/how-do-i-find-out-how-many-bytes-a-character-has

Comment: Er... I think your edit has made the question even more confusing.

Answer (score 5):

In PHP a character always maps one-to-one on a single octet, ie. a byte. As such `strlen` correctly returns the number of bytes in a single string - although it might consume more memory because of internal representation (trailing zero or length integer).

To support multibyte notations you need to use the [mbstring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mbstring.php) functions.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php.  A character is the same as a byte, according to that page.

Also, a character can be multiple bytes (multibyte), depending on the encoding.  From my experience, you would need to have the [mbstring extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) enabled for that.  If you don't know if your characters are multiple bytes, then each character is probably one byte.